# javascript: how to manage a div with no ID

Tags: javascript, html

my page is full of php-generated content split in div's that have the same class but no id's. I want to show some buttons that allow me to manage, change and delete the div's; the buttons should be able to change the class, delete the div and select the content of the div.
How can I do this? is there a way to set the button's onclick action to something, say ... onclick="changetheclass(this)" that would actually change the class of the div containing this button?

Man I feel I'm not making any sense here :(
Did anyone understand what I'm talking about? If so, is there any possibility to do this?
Thanks in advance!
:)

EDIT: this is one of the divs, so that you could understand what I'm talking about:

```
    <div class="box"><p>
    this is the content of the div
    <button onclick="change_the_class(this_div_or_something)">click here to change the class of the div</a>
    <button onclick="select_the_content(this_div_or_something)">click here to change the class of the div</a>
    <button onclick="delete_the_whole_div(this_div_or_something)">click here to change the class of the div</a>
</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for ??

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function changeClass(elm) {
               elm.parentNode.className ='newcss';
           }

           function deleteDiv(elm) {
               var par = elm.parentNode;
               var gran = par.parentNode;
               gran.removeChild(par);
           }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='test'>
            Hello
            <button onclick="javascript:changeClass(this);" value="Change CSS">CSS</button>
            <button onclick="javascript:deleteDiv(this);" value="Change CSS">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class='test'>
            Hello
            <button onclick="javascript:changeClass(this);" value="Change CSS">CSS</button>
            <button onclick="javascript:deleteDiv(this);" value="Change CSS">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class='test'>
            Hello
            <button onclick="javascript:changeClass(this);" value="Change CSS">CSS</button>
            <button onclick="javascript:deleteDiv(this);" value="Change CSS">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class='test'>
            Hello
            <button onclick="javascript:changeClass(this);" value="Change CSS">CSS</button>
            <button onclick="javascript:deleteDiv(this);" value="Change CSS">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am going to test this, but I think that's exactly what I am looking for! thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

in JS, you can use [querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryse):

```
//get all divs with class "myDiv"
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.myDiv');

//for each of the gathered divs, do something with it
for(var i=0; i< divs.length;i++){
    var aDiv = divs[i];

    //"aDiv" is a div in the collection of matched divs
    //you can do anything with it: add buttons etc.

}
```

Comment: That will match all divs, not the one with the class he want to targets.

Answer (score 0):

First stay away from `onclick="something"` - [inline JavaScript](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/). then yes you can still manage to do what you want to do without ids.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    result = [],
    len = divs.length,
    i = 0,
    aLink;

for(; i < len; i++){
    // update the condition if there can be more than one class name as this assume a single class name
    if (divs[i].className == 'myClassName') result.push(divs[i]);
}

len = result.length;
i = 0;

for (; i < len; i++) {
aLink = document.createElement('a');
aLink.innerHTML = 'Edit';
aLink._parent = result[i]; // store a reference to the parent div
aLink.href = '#';
aLink.onclick = function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
// do your edit stuff here, ev.target._parent contain the targetted div
};
result[i].appendChild(aLink);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div.my-class').each( function( index, element ){
   var div = $( element ); // not sure if this is needed

   // add the buttons, e.g. via div.html('');

   // add the buttons' click handlers    
});
```

Comment: do people still use javascript directly these days?

Comment: -1, for the obvious (jQuery not tagged). jQuery and JS are **not** synonymous.